# nameTuple and class parameters

Tags: python, class, namedtuple

My lecturer wrote some code and I have no idea how to read it and google isn't helping, can someone please clarify how this code interacts.

```
yield Arc(tail_node, head = tail_node - 1, label="1down", cost=1)
```

Is the method call for the class

```
class Arc(namedtuple('Arc', 'tail, head, label, cost')):
```

The class Arc contains no methods, and no __init. I have no clue how these two are interacting since I thought class parameters accepted another class, and it made the current class a subclass or abstract etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) function is a class factory. It takes some parameters and returns a class. The class inherits from `tuple`, but its values are also accessible by name as attributes (not only by index).

The `Arc` class you show uses `namedtuple` to create its base class. You could equivalently write it with separate statements, giving the base class it's own name:

```
Base = namedtuple('Arc', 'tail, head, label, cost')   # this creates a class
class Arc(Base):    # this class inherits from the base class
    pass
```

If the `Arc` class doesn't have *any* methods of its own, there wouldn't be much point in defining it at all (you'd just use the name `Arc` instead of `Base` for the class returned from `namedtuple`). I'm guessing there is some more code in the `Arc` class, just not anything relevant to your question. The behavior inherited from the base class is enough to create instances using positional or keyword arguments, so the `yield` statement you show doesn't need any additional code.